# using rollupjs with moment-timezone

Tags: webpack, timezone, momentjs, rollupjs

I have a package that depends on `moment-timezone`. The package is used in a website bundled with webpack 2.

We now bundle it with rollupjs, which is great because it seems better than compile it to ES5.

The problem that we have now is to manage timezone. How can I get the `moment` instance and inject a specific timezone.

Previously, the moment instance was global, so we could change the locale from the website. Now it seems that the moment instance is local.

How can I "share" the moment instance between the package and the website?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a script to recreate the environment or at least provide greater detail about the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my issue by using dependency injection.

I injected the moment instance in my package, and use the same instance though.